# How to run CoSign Signature SOAP API code in java 1.6 version of IBM Lotus Notes?

Tags: java, soap, digital-signature, cosign-api

I am having problem while using code for adding digital signature to pdf file. Here is the link of the code http://developer.arx.com/quick-start/sapi-web-services/#tab=t-helloworld . There are some classes in the code which are needed to import in before running, but the package of these classes isn't available in java version 1.6, I am using IBM lotus notes which supports upto java version 1.6. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java classes in the code sample were indeed generated with Java version 1.7. All you need is to generate new classes compatible with your own environment. [Here](http://developer.arx.com/quick-start/sapi-web-services/#tab=t-getstarted&lang=glang-java) you can find an explanation on how to do it using the **wsimport** JDK utility.

Comment: I have tried generating classes using wsimport. The problem I have faced is, it generates classes for "com.arx.sapiws.spml._1" and "oasis.names.tc.spml" instead of "com.arx.sapiws.dss._1" and "oasis.names.tc.dss" which is used in code.

Comment: Notice that the SDK contains two WSDL files: SAPIWS-DSS.wsdl- for signature and validation related functions; SAPIWS-SPML.wsdl- for user management related functions. It seems that you generated the SPML classes, do the same with the DSS WSDL file to generate the DSS classes.

Comment: I have tried the same procedure for SAPIWS-DSS.wsdl file, I have got some errors on prompt.
1> warning: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 's1:SignRequest' to a(n) 'element
 declaration' component.
2> warning: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xml:lang' to a(n) 'attribute decl
 aration' component.
3> warning: s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'InternationalStringType' is
 invalid.  Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
4> warning: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 's2:NameIdentifierType' to a(n) 't
 ype definition' component.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Those are all warnings, and in that case wsimport should still generate the classes. Besides those warnings, is there any error that you didn't mention?

Comment: I am getting these warnings and the classes are not generating for "SAPIWS-DSS.wsdl". I am writing "wsimport -keep -extension <filepath/filename>" in the java/bin folder. Am I missing something which I should include?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am tempted. I have tried the procedure given in the comment above but unfortunately it isn't working. All I need is the classes, so do you know any other source from where I could download the jar file or its corresponding classes.

Comment: Here you go - https://app.box.com/s/md0uckuazsdl7fc280sx (DSS Jars for Java v1.6)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, all the classes are working now, but I got stuck in code part. I got stuck in the "DSS" class. The line of code is "DSS client = new DSS(new URL(wsdlUrl));" whereas the DSS method of our defined class takes 2 parameters DSS(url,qname), so it throws error on 1 parameter DSS(url). I have tried default value of "qname" shown in class "QName("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/", "DSS")", but it throws error "java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader)". I got stuck here, Am I missing something?

Comment: I have made changes in java.policy < permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader"> but unfortunately it won't work. I've also added "System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("setContextClassLoader"));" in the code. It too don't work. The "arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/" link redirects to "arx.com". So I think it might be the cause for "AccessControlException".

Comment: After changing the DSS() parameters, I am getting "java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader)" error, Do you have any idea of this error? Should I change some properties or parameters?

Comment: The line- "DSS client = new DSS(new URL(wsdlUrl));" should be changed with this one- "DSS client = new DSS(new URL(wsdlUrl), new QName("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/", "DSS"));". Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the line to "DSS client = new DSS(new URL(wsdlUrl), new QName("arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/";, "DSS"));". The link "arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/" redirects to "arx.com". It is also not working while providing the local path ie "new QName("file:/C:/Users/<my folder path>/com/arx/sapiws/dss/_1/","DSS")".

Comment: Try to replace the JCE policy files (at ${java.home}/lib/security/) with these- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Comment: Hi, As suggested I have made the changes in JCE policy files, it still throws the same error message "java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader)". One more thing I have noticed, while opening the link "arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/" manually on web browser, it redirects to "arx.com". Is this acceptable or it might be a problem?

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea regarding this issue I have mentioned in my last comment, as I am still struggling with this issue.

Comment: It would best if I could see your code. Can you add it as a new question and share a code snippet?

Comment: Hi, I have posted the question along with the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299584/how-to-run-cosign-signature-soap-api-in-ibm-lotus-notes, I haven't posted my actual credentials of CoSign in my code.

Comment: Hi, The "AccessControlException" is resolved now. Can you have a look into my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484147/how-to-change-the-coordinates-of-signature-in-cosign-signature-soap-api-and-plac