# How to Sign a PDF File using Field Locators using Java including its necessary jar (i.e. java packages)?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, cosign-api

I am having a C# code for signing a PDF file using Field Locator in the given link
http://developer.arx.com/examples/sapi-local-csharp-signing-a-pdf-file-using-field-locators/
I need Java compatible code and its necessary java packages to achieve the same. Also you can have a look into my previous question [How to change the coordinates of Signature in CoSign Signature SOAP API and place it over some given text (i.e. Sign Here)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484147/how-to-change-the-coordinates-of-signature-in-cosign-signature-soap-api-and-plac) querying the same.

Answer (score 1):

A [code example](http://developer.arx.com/examples/sapi-web-services-java-signing-a-pdf-file-using-field-locators/) in Java that demonstrates how to use the Field Locators with SAPI Web Services is now available in the CoSign DevPortal.